# How to use one .env for all docker services

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm learning Docker, and I have question about environments.

Project structure:

- nginx (Dockerfile)
- nuxt.js + express.js (Dockerfile)
- laravel (Dockerfile)
- mysql (Dockerfile)
- docker compose

I need to save all settings variables in root folder with `docker-compose`. But laravel needs `.env` file inside their root dir.

So my question is: Is there some path to store all settings in one `.env` file in the root directory, and when docker-compose run, it give that setting to all services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your docker-compose.yml, you can either declare a volume mount for a directory containing your .env file. Then read from that directory in your laravel application for example.

Or you can choose to use the `env_file` configuration option to give the running process access to those variables.

```
services:
  foo:
    image: foo
    volumes:
      - ./env:/app/env

  bar:
    image: bar
    env_file: ./env/.env
```

[Read more here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)